# I am getting a type error on my code where it says your_value1 = ((20)/miles_gallon)*dollars_gallon . I am not sure how to resolve the type error

Tags: python, typeerror

```
miles_gallon = input()
dollars_gallon = input()

your_value1 = ((20)/miles_gallon)*dollars_gallon
your_value2 = 75
your_value3 = 100

print(f'({your_value1:.2f} {your_value2:.2f} {your_value3:.2f})')
```

I attempted to resolve the issue by change the math operations, but I believe I need to specify         that the value is a type float.

Comment: You can't divide strings, which is what `input()` gives you. You need to convert to numbers first. Please, next time extract a [mcve], which would probably have given you enough hint to solve this yourself. Also, quote the full error output that code then produces. Further, you can also search online for the error message to get an idea what it means. As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

The error message (that you failed to post) is pretty clear.

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str'
```

says, that your operands to '/' are not supported. That is, the implementation for '/' does not accept an int to the left and str to the right.
Which makes sense. How would you want to divide an integer by a string?
So, if you try casting the string into an int or float:

```
miles_gallon = int(input())
```

it would work. Note that if you type a non numeric string it will tell you exactly when trying the conversion:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'e'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
miles_gallon = float(input())
dollars_gallon = float(input())

your_value1 = ((20)/miles_gallon)*dollars_gallon
your_value2 = 75
your_value3 = 100

print(f'({your_value1:.2f} {your_value2:.2f} {your_value3:.2f})')
```

Comment: I added the float(input()) to the code and that gave me the desired output.  Thank you all for your support.

Comment: If somebody takes the time to answer your question, you might take the time to accept an answer if it helped.